# Toyota Tacoma running high rpm

Tags: toyota, rpm, tacoma

I have a 2003 Toyota Tacoma 4wd with manual transmission. It is running at 4000 rpms at 70 mph. What would cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What should it be running? Is this different than it had been running before?

Comment: Maybe a slipping clutch that is worn out.

Comment: Have you fitted different tires?

Comment: It should be 2500-3000. I have not changed anything on it. The high rpm and high idle are the only problems I am having with it.

Comment: "High idle" ... what does it idle at?

Comment: It idle around 2200. It was around 1000